# Django: csrf_token doesn't work after deploy

Tags: django, nginx, csrf, gunicorn, django-csrf

I deploying my `Django` project in `AWS` (`nginx`, `gunicorn`)

I can access my project through url and looking great. But problem is that I can not send any `POST` request because of `csrf_token` error.

[image]

I just googled it and find looks-good solution : http://www.regisblog.fr/2014/08/31/passing-django-csrf-cookie-nginx/

But it doesn't work after I edited `nginx.conf`.

Here is my `nginx.conf` (`ssl` not applying yet and conceal IP address)

```
worker_processes  1;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    accept_mutex off;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  MY_IP;

        client_max_body_size 4G;
        keepalive_timeout 5;

        #return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        location / {
            proxy_pass_header X-CSRFToken;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4349;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }
}
```

Advice me please, thanks.

Comment: Is this happening on all of your pages?

Comment: yes, all post request page, login, singup, admin-login etc

Comment: I don't know if it plays a role, but you have an error at `X-Forwarded-Proto`; should be `http`.

Comment: If you're using HTTPS you'll need to set secure cookies in settings `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True` and
`SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True`

Comment: @AntonisChristofides you save my life

Comment: @markwalker_ Thanks for advice! I will consider it after I apply ssl

Comment: Ah, I see, with your `X-Forwarded-Proto` I thought you were already running https!